# Calculate offset cumulative sum begining with 0 for each group

Tags: r

My sample data looks like this:

```
>         gros id nr_oriz
>      1:   23  1       1
>      2:   16  1       2
>      3:   14  1       3
>      4:   15  1       4
>      5:   22  1       5
>      6:   30  1       6
>      7:   25  2       1
>      8:   10  2       2
>      9:   13  2       3
>     10:   17  2       4
>     11:   45  2       5
>     12:   25  4       1
>     13:   15  4       2
>     14:   20  4       3
>     15:   20  4       4
>     16:   20  4       5
```

where `gros` is the depth for each soil horizon, `id` is the profile number and `nr_horiz` is soil horizon number. I need to create two columns: top and bottom, where top is the upper limit of horizon and bottom the lower limit. We have managed to obtain only the bottom values using:

```
topsoil$bottom<-ave(topsoil$gros,topsoil$id,FUN=cumsum)
```

but for top values we need somehow to offset the data for each `id` and to calculate cumulative sum beginning from 0 and without the last value, like in this example:

```
    gros id nr_oriz top bottom
 1:   23  1       1   0     23
 2:   16  1       2  23     39
 3:   14  1       3  39     53
 4:   15  1       4  53     68
 5:   22  1       5  68     90
 6:   30  1       6  90    120
 7:   25  2       1   0     25
 8:   10  2       2  25     35
 9:   13  2       3  35     48
10:   17  2       4  48     65
11:   45  2       5  65    110
12:   25  4       1   0     25
13:   15  4       2  25     40
14:   20  4       3  40     60
15:   20  4       4  60     80
16:   20  4       5  80    100
```

Is there a simple solution for this, taking into account that the database is very large and we cannot do it manually (as we did with `top` column in this sample).

Comment: you could try something like `library(data.table); setDT(topsoil)[ , top := c(0, cumsum(gros)), by = id]`

Comment: It seems that you have a `data.table` object there, so I would suggested you learn the proper `data.table` syntax. You can start [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use `ave` again, but on the "bottom" column and with a custom function:

```
topsoil$top <- ave(topsoil$bottom, topsoil$id, FUN=function(x) c(0,x[-length(x)]))
```

---

As it appears you are using the `data.table` package, you could modify your code to take advantage of data.table's syntax and performance. In order to calculate `bottom`, you would simply do:

```
topsoil[, bottom := cumsum(gros), by = id]
```

Then to calculate `top`:

```
topsoil[, top := c(0L, bottom[-.N]), by = id]
```

Or you can wrap them up in a single step similarly to how was illustrated by [@akrun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31540718/271616).

Comment: It worked with the first line but I intend to use both solutions in the future.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this with `shift` from the devel version of `data.table`.  Instructions to install the devel version are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
setDT(topsoil)[, c('top', 'bottom'):= {tmp <- cumsum(gros)
          list(top= shift(tmp, fill=0), bottom=tmp)}, by = id]
topsoil
#    gros id nr_oriz top bottom
# 1:   23  1       1   0     23
# 2:   16  1       2  23     39
# 3:   14  1       3  39     53
# 4:   15  1       4  53     68
# 5:   22  1       5  68     90
# 6:   30  1       6  90    120
# 7:   25  2       1   0     25
# 8:   10  2       2  25     35
# 9:   13  2       3  35     48
#10:   17  2       4  48     65
#11:   45  2       5  65    110
#12:   25  4       1   0     25
#13:   15  4       2  25     40
#14:   20  4       3  40     60
#15:   20  4       4  60     80
#16:   20  4       5  80    100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>%
       mutate(bottom = cumsum(gros), top = lag(bottom)) %>%
       replace(is.na(.), 0)
```